# SAS % let statement

Tags: sas

I am facing an issue with the % let statement I have not found yet the correct answer, and I am not sure if something can be done.

I am facing the following issue, hope someone can help.

I have this macro statement.

```
%let num = 5;
%let c&num.act = %str(re&num);
```

I want that the `%let c&num.act` gets the value `c5.act`, but it is not working this way.

So the last let statement is resolve this way:

```
c5.act = re5
```

Can you give me some help?

Comment: I don't understand.  You cannot make a macro variable with a period in its name.  Note that your second %LET is NOT making a macro variable with a period in its name because the period is being used by the macro processor to locate the end of the macro variable being referenced.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at us when you're us for free help to solve **your** problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the question is NOT about %LET statements.  Instead you seem to be confused about how to reference the macro variable that you created with the %LET statement.

So these two statements

```
%let num=5;
%let c&num.act = re&num;
```

create two macro variables.  NUM and C5ACT.

To see the values you can use code like this:

```
%put &num;
%put &&c&num.act ;
```

When you have two & triggers next to each other the macro processor will replace them with a single & and remind itself to re-process the resulting string for further macro expansion.
On the first pass `&&c&num.act` will be transformed into `&c5act` which will then be re-evaluated and result in value re5 that was assigned by the second %LET statement.